# What's the best way to add JQuery to Enduro.js

Tags: enduro.js

I'd like to be able to use Jquery in my Enduro.js project, but there is not a single sample using it on github Enduro.js page

Libraries seem to be loaded in Enduro.js using RequireJS, wth the line found at the bottom of the default index.hbs :

```
{{!-- <script data-main="/assets/js/main.js" src="/assets/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script> --}}
```

and the following code found un "assets/js/main.js" by default in all Enduro.js samples :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/assets/',

    paths: {
        // 'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    },
})

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('requirejs ready to use')
    })
})
```

The Jquery "path" line is commented out, and there is no /vendor directory in /assets by default.

Is there an automated way to install jquery in Enduro.js or is it just simply about creating by hand a /vendor folder, and copying /Jquery inside it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to use JQuery in Enduro. I'm not sure if it is the best way to import it (it could exist better ones).

In my current project, I'm using the CDN for reasons of efficiency. If you have no problem using CDNs I'd recommend it.

just copy this code:

```
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

And then, paste it just before closing the body tag.

Another way is to create a folder inside /assets/js called 'vendor' and there, you cat put the jquery-3.3.x.min.js (Or whatever version you would like to use). Of course, you have to download it first from the official site.

After doing that, you just have to import it via HTML (before closing body tag):

```
<script src="assets/js/vendor/jqueryfile.js"></script>
```

NOTE: Creating the folder called 'vendor' is optional, you just could paste the file inside /assets/js. And make sure you type the right path to import it.

NOTE 2: remember that you should never touch the files inside _generated, so if you paste the file inside _genereated/assets/js, everything is going to work, but when you migrate your site to production or anywhere else the app will crash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Actually I did use the CDN solution (inserted after the {{/with}} in the index.hbs

Comment: Ok, now that JS Compiling is enabled, I am unable to compile /assets/main.js (the file with contains 'put your js here')... The file is not compiled by Enduro.js, I guess it should be.

Comment: Go to the path of your project in the terminal and type: enduro render. That probably works. (and don't forget to restart the server).

Comment: nope, only /cms/index.js gets its content compiled and executed. After checking things out though, I managed to get a JS compile error, if I put trash in /assets/js/main.js but it doesn't seem to be executed (a simple console.log('blabla'); gives no results (in terminal or javascript console) - I'm running "enduro dev" in terminal on osx by the way.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird, have you made sure you already imported it into the HTML with the script tag?

Comment: Hmm no :p do you mean I have to manually import the default main.js provided at install ? (didn't think about that!) - a simple <script type="text/javascript"src="/assets/js/main.js"></script> will do the trick ?

Comment: okay, it did the trick :) (I didn't use require.js as suggested in samples, is it okay ?)